# Physical exercises with muscle activation

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset containing a list of physical exercises with muscle activation and ideally the reference that quantified the muscle activation.

For example, the physical exercises Crunch, Abflex, Nautilus, Nordic, Abroller, and Sit-up have the following muscle activation according to (1)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

- (1) Beim, Gloria M., Jorge L. Giraldo, Danny M. Pincivero, Matthew J. Borror, and Freddie H. Fu. "Abdominal strengthening exercises: a comparative EMG study." Journal of Sport Rehabilitation 6 (1997): 11-20. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14268144323214177148&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://journals.humankinetics.com/AcuCustom/Sitename/Documents/DocumentItem/2115.pdf ; http://pitt.edu/~neurolab/publications/1997/Articles/BeimGM_1997_JSportRehab_Abdominal%20strengthening%20exercise-a%20comparative%20EMG%20study.pdf